# Are the unitaries $XZ$ and $Y$ equivalent to each other in the circuit model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

In a recent discussion with a colleague I massively confused myself and was hoping for some clarification/resolution to my confusion.

So the claim was that implementing the $X.Z$ gate is equivalent to implementing the $Y$ gate, as the global phase is irrelevant. However any Clifford circuit is often stated as being composed of Pauli gates ($\mathbb{I},X,Y,Z$) and non-Pauli Clifford gates (e.g. Hadamard, Phase and CNOTs). However if $XZ$ is equivalent to $Y$, isn't the inclusion of $Y$ redundant?

Any information I have found online always states gates sets as being composed of $\mathbb{I}, X, Y, Z$ with no mention of this equivalence.

My best attempt at understandings as why $Y$ is included, rather than just $XZ$, is motivated by observables, as $XZ$ doesn't stabilize any state we use $Y$ to keep unitaries and observables consistent. My other attempt feels a bit more feeble, and relies on the fact that $Y$ is self-adjoint, i.e. $Y^\dagger = Y$, where as $XZ$ isn't, $(XZ)^\dagger = -XZ$. So in a circuit where we want to replace $Y$ with $XZ$ we'd have to keep track of whether we were applying the adjoint of $Y$ or $Y$, regardless of their equivalence operationally. To illustrate this suppose I want to measure an observable $Y\mathcal{O}Y$, well I could equivalently implement the circuit; $Y$ gate followed by measuring $\mathcal{O}$ followed by another $Y$ gate. However if I wanted to use $XZ$ instead the final $Y$ needs to be replaced by $-XZ$, for the circuits to be equivalent (or I could flip the outcome of $\mathcal{O}$ assuming it's a binary valued observable). However this seems to break the the statement that I can just replace $Y$ with $XZ$, as I have had to change the gate I choose to implement. But again this seems to just be up to a global phase?

I feel like I am being really dumb and missing something so thank you for any responses :).

Comment: All Paulis are redundant for Clifford circuits.  Hadamard, CNOT and phase are sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it's pretty common to use XZ instead of Y. Whether it's more or less convenient depends on what you're doing. The differences only *really* matter when you start adding controls to operations, and global phases become control-dependent phases. It's mostly a matter of personal choice and convenience in the moment.

One choice of basis sets is the Pauli matrices $\{I,X,Y,Z\}$. The classic choice. All the elements are unitary, Hermitian, and square to $I$.

Another possible choice is $\{I, iX, iY, iZ\}$. This set is isomorphic to the quaternions, and all of its elements have determinant 1. Sometimes mathematically convenient, sometimes awkward because $(iX)^2 = (iY)^2 = (iZ)^2 = -I \neq I = I^2$.

And of course there's {I, X, XZ, Z}. This set is easy to parametrize by two bits as $X^a Z^b$. This makes it convenient for circuits. For example, it's what superdense coding uses. But now there's even more awkwardness with signs: $(XZ)^2 =-I \neq I = X^2 = Y^2 = I^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your response :).  This makes more sense to me now. I still find it kind of weird to use gates that are not stabilizer operations. However I am right to paraphrase: as long as you are consistent in your implementation of these different sets, they are equivalent.